# Increase MySQL InnoDB table size on Mac OS X

Tags: mysql, macos, innodb

InnoDB MySQL table data size is 15 GB, index size is 2.4 GB, number of rows is ~ 16 000 000. I tryed to add new columns to table, but operation failed with error

```
Mysql2::Error: The table 'table2' is full: ALTER TABLE `table2` ADD `new_field` ...
```

My disk has about 10GB free space.

What is problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is disk space. After I cleanup my drive, disk free space was increased to 50 Gb and problem is gone.